# Triangle Rasterization: Bresenham's in 3D

Tags: c++, graphics, bresenham

I am looking for a 3D implementation of triangle rasterization using Bresenham's line drawing algorithm. Namely, I have this source:

http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/java/TriangleRasterization/TriangleRasterization.html,

however the algorithm is in 2D. Is there any way I can extend this to 3D?

Thank you

Comment: Do you really mean that you want to discretize the triangle to obtain a set of contiguous voxels ?

Comment: Interestingly, this is *not* how triangles are typically rasterized - even in software. Triangles with adjacent edges shouldn't overdraw (share) pixels, and there are half-open interval and tie-breaking conventions that are strictly observed. I think these concepts would extend to voxels for 'watertight' rendering.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, yes that is what I mean. I am working on an application where I want to "walk" the interior of the triangle and examine the space that the triangle occupies(with its interior), if that makes sense. By using the information concerning where the triangle is located and the space that it takes up, I want to map this information to determine where the triangle is in my voxelization of the environment.

Comment: A triangle is a flat object an has no "interior" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a posted 3D Bresenham [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21057-3d-bresenhams-line-generation/content/bresenham_line3d.m). The code is in matlab script, but I believe it would be straightforward to convert it to C++.

Comment: Bresenham, please. :-)

Answer (score 1):

As a first attempt, you can try to modify one of the 2D standard or Bresenham *triangle* algorithms so as to compute (X, Z) coordinates instead of X alone (computing intersections in the XZ plane or drawing with the 3D Bresenham *line* algorithm) and join the points using the 2D Bresenham *line* algorithm between these, instead of a simple row of pixels.